# How to define function arguments based on data.frame columns (R)?

Tags: r, function

I have a script that runs maximum likelihood estimation for a linear model. The model has several variables and I need to vary them occasionally, maybe add or drop some. The usual way to define the likelihood function is like this:

```
LL <- function(beta0, beta1, beta2, mu, sigma){
   R = y - beta0*X$x0 + beta1*X$x1 + beta2*X$x2
   R = dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log = T)
   -sum(R)
}
```

I have dependent variable in vector y and covariates in data.frame X:

```
X <- data.frame(x0 = 1, x1 = runif(100), x2 = runif(100)*2)
y <- X$x0 + X$x1 + X$x2 + rnorm(100)
```

Now the amount of variables is subject to change by application and I need to reformulate the function so that it will take as many covariates as there are columns in the data.frame X. I was already able to reformulate this to a more general form:

```
cols <- 0:(ncol(X)-1)
betas <- paste0("beta", cols)
eqR <- paste0("y - ", paste0(betas, "*X$x", cols, collapse = " - "))

LL <- function(beta0, beta1, beta2, mu, sigma){
   R = as.formula(eqR)
   R = dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log = T)
   -sum(R)
}
```

I'm still struggling to find a way to dynamically define the function so that it would take the same number of beta arguments as there are columns in the covariate matrix. Ellipsis is perhaps useful here? I also tried with `do.call`:

```
LL <- function(betas, mu, sigma){
   R <- do.call(dnorm(as.formula(eqR), mu, sigma, log = T), betas)
   -sum(R)
}
```

That doesn't work when you fit the model, which has another stumbling block in the list of initial values:

```
require(stats4)
fit <- mle(LL, start = list(beta0 = 0, beta1 = 0, beta2 = 0, mu = 0, sigma = 1))
```

Any ideas for this?

EDIT:

I made some advance with `bbmle` package:

```
require(bbmle)

dfModel <- cbind(y, X)
cols <- 0:(ncol(X)-1)
betas <-paste0("beta",cols)

betaList <- as.list(rep(0), length(betas)))
names(betaList) <- betas
initList <- c(betaList, mu = 0, sigma = 1)

fitML <- mle2(mu ~ dnorm(mean = y - beta0*x0 - beta1*x1 - beta2*x2, sd = sigma),
              start = initList,
              data = dfModel)
```

The above example works. But when I try to define the function beforehand with as.formula, I can't get it working. So the following does not work.

```
eqR <- paste0("y - ", paste0(betas, "*x", cols, collapse = " - "))

fitML <- mle2(mu ~ dnorm(mean = as.formula(eqR), sd = sigma),
              start = initList,
              data = dfModel)
```

The error message is:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'beta0' not found

I suspect that this might have something to do with scoping - conflict between dnorm and as.formula? I just can't find workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
betas = c(0,0,0)
X <- data.frame(x0 = 1, x1 = runif(100), x2 = runif(100)*2)
y <- apply(X,1,sum) + rnorm(100)
```

where `betas` is (b0, b1, b2, ...etc) and its length must be equal to the number of columns of `X`.
Since X could have a different number of columns `y` should be defined as above.

Your LL function should change to:

```
LL <- function(betas, mu, sigma){

    R = y - as.matrix(X) %*% as.matrix(betas)

    R = dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log = T)
    -sum(R)
}
```

where `%*%` is the matrix product. This is the same as doing `b[1]*X[,1] + b[2]*X[,2] + b[3]*X[,3] + ... + b[n]*X[,n]`

With these changes, you could have data frame `X` with any number of columns, `betas` an array of the same length as columns of `X`.

I hope I understood what you needed.

Comment: This does not work because function LL is passed as an argument to  function stats4::mle. Therefore LL needs to have all its arguments in a kind of a list form, which is quite inflexible. So if I modify my model by e.g. adding one variable, I need to modify script in three locations. That is what I want to avoid.